# AspectJ - Logging HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to hijack an HTTPServletRequest and log some values from it using AspectJ.  However, what ends up in the JoinPoint is a "RequestFacade" object.  There doesn't seem to be much that I can do with this object.  Is my logging strategy all wrong?  How can I get useful information from the HttpServletRequest?  If I have to unwrap it prior to calling a method, that sort of defeats the purpose of AOP in my application.

I am using a Glassfish server, if that makes a difference.

```
@Before("execution(* Service.testAuditRecord(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("logBefore  --->"  + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("logBefore--->Args : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
}
```

The RequestFacade record

```
INFO: logBefore  --->testAuditRecord
INFO: logBefore--->Args : [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4dbfa7d0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) is an interface. Each servlet container has its own implementation. `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade` is one of them.

That being said you are free to use any of the methods of `HttpServletRequest`, without bothering about the actual implementation.

What is the signature of `Service.testAuditRecord()`? Does it take `HttpServletRequest` as an argument? If so, AspectJ should give you a strongly typed instance without much hassle. Try this:

```
@Before("execution(* Service.testAuditRecord(..)) && args(request)")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint, HttpServletRequest request) {
  //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RequestContextHolder` like

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) 
RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```